# How to access/print the auxiliary vector entry in main?

Tags: c, linux, stack

[image]

According to the image,the stack is populated with the auxiliary vector entry on start up.

I don't know of it before.

How can I access/print them?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);
```

Does it mean `main` has a hidden fourth parameter?

Comment: Are you aware that these kinds of details are always system dependent?

Comment: They are on the stack. You can use inline ASM to access the stack.

Comment: @dmckee ,that's fine, I just need the idea and will figure out the exact case for specific system.

Comment: @Stan ,what's the type ? I need to know this to print them out.

Comment: @lexer - As it's implementation-related, I'm not sure. You can check your documentation -- Generally, 'entries' mean pointers.

Answer (score 4):

The aux vector is located immediately past the end of the environment vector, which is accessible (per POSIX) as `extern char **environ;`. `environ` points to a NULL-pointer terminated array of `char *` pointers to environment variables. Iterate through the environment until you reach `NULL`, then advance one element further and cast the result to whatever type you want to use to access the aux vector. Personally, I treat it as an array of `size_t` or `uintptr_t` values that come in pairs, since this is easier and more portable than the `elf.h` `Elf32_auxv_t` and `Elf64_auxv_t` types (which require that you special-case whether you're building for a 32-bit or 64-bit target).

Note that the existence and location of the aux vector are not specified by POSIX, but this is where they will be located on any ELF-ABI-based implementation that use an aux vector.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is system specific. The C ISO defines only two arguments to the `main` function. Additional arguments are not standard and should be considered an extension. Quoting [Main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) from Wikipedia:

> The parameters argc, argument count, and argv, argument vector, [1] respectively give the number and value of the program's command-line arguments. The names of argc and argv may be any valid identifier in C, but it is common convention to use these names. In C++, the names are to be taken literally, and the "void" in the parameter list is to be omitted, if strict conformance is desired. [2] Other platform-dependent formats are also allowed by the C and C++ standards, except that in C++ the return type must stay int; for example, Unix (though not POSIX.1) and Microsoft Windows have a third argument giving the program's environment, otherwise accessible through getenv in stdlib.h:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
```

> Mac OS X and Darwin have a fourth parameter containing arbitrary OS-supplied information, such as the path to the executing binary: [3]

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple)
```

**The AMD64 ABI**

According to the [System V ABI for AMD64, Draft 0.99.5](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.5.pdf), the auxiliary vector entries are of type `auxv_t`, as shown below:

[image: The AMD64 ABI uses the auxiliary vector types deﬁned in ﬁgure 3.11.]